# Tensorflow.keras - load files from custom directory structure

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have following folders structure for image segmentation:
train:

```
../input/hand-seg-tr/train/a/images  (Images)
../input/hand-seg-tr/train/a/segmentation (Masks)

..

../input/hand-seg-tr/train/z/images
../input/hand-seg-tr/train/z/segmentation

test (unlabeled):

../input/hand-segmentation-test/test/images/0.png
```

How can I load files with something like image_dataset_from_directory, flow_from_directory?

I have idea to just flatten a..z folders to one, but maybe there are better solutions?

Comment: Does [reading multiple files in TF2](https://biswajitsahoo1111.github.io/post/reading-multiple-files-in-tensorflow-2/) help you? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe. Thanks. I already did it with glob and dataset (from filelist / slice)